# Change the flex-direction value to column in Safari and the first flex-item covers the page

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Sample:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

body:hover {
  flex-direction: column;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}

div#tan {
  background: tan;
}

div#teal {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="tan"></div>
<div id="teal"></div>
```

Hover your mouse over the page and here's what you see in Safari 10, macOS Sierra:

[image]

And here's how it's supposed to look:

[image]

Why do other flex items disappear? What's the solution?

Comment: If you set the column direction straight (not on hover), does it still not show properly?

Comment: Then it looks all right.